# Get date from DB and pass to view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner with using Laravel. 
I would ask you about pass data from DB to view.

Code:

```
{!! Form::select('unit_id', $units, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

In controller i am trying get value from DB and pass to view.

```
  $units = DB::table('units')
  ->select('id', 'name')
  ->get();Title
  $title = 'Create New Dets';
  return view('dets.create', ['title' => $title, 'units' => $units]);
```

I am tried with compact etc.

Maybe i should use Model? This table is only for units.

Could someone explain me how i should do it?

Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the values to blade view you have to

```
return view('dets.create', compact( 'title', 'units'));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following:

```
  $units = DB::table('units')
            ->select('id', 'name')
             ->pluck('name','id');
 $title = 'Create New Dets';
 return view('dets.create', ['title' => $title, 'units' => $units]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the $units? I mean check it whether it has data or not.

```
dd($units);
```

if it has data you can pass it in multiple ways i.e. using compact, as an array in the form of

> key=value

**compact case:**

```
return view('dets.create', compact('title', 'units'));
```

**array case:**

```
return view('dets.create', ['title' => $title, 'units' => $units]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your data in the form of key and value

```
{!! Form::select('unit_id', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

in controller

```
$units = Units::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```